# Changing Tray Icon when script is paused

Tags: scripting, windows-10, autohotkey

I have googled a bit, but I'm not able to find how to do this. I need custom icon when script is paused/suspended. I know how to change it on key press, but I need same functionality like when you suspend it with right mouse click in System Tray. When you do that standard AHK icon will have red background, if paused and it will change letter to "S" if suspended. My script needs to change to custom icon when it's paused/suspended, when you right-click on the icon in Tray and suspend it. No key press activation needed, eventually script need to detect when I pause/resume it and change to different custom icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tray icon at any time, so you can do so before you pause and return it back to normal when you unpause the script like so:

```
; start of script
Menu, Tray, Icon, normal.ico

; pause icon
Menu, Tray, Icon, paused.ico
Pause, On

; return to normal    
Menu, Tray, Icon, normal.ico
Pause, Off
```

See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm#Icon

Edit: make your own tray menu, very basic code you need to expand to turn it on/off, simply to illustrate

```
Menu, Tray, Icon, normal.ico, , 1
Menu, tray, NoStandard ; removes edit, pause, reload etc
; other menu options
Menu, tray, Add, &Suspend Hotkeys     , MenuHandler
Menu, tray, Icon,&Suspend Hotkeys     , %A_AhkPath%, 3 ; default suspend     icon
Menu, tray, Add, &Pause Script        , MenuHandler
Menu, tray, Icon,&Pause Script        , %A_AhkPath%, 4 ; default pause icon

; 

MenuHandler:
;
If (A_ThisMenuItem = "&Pause Script")
{
 Menu, Tray, Icon, paused.ico
 Pause
 Return
}
```

Comment: Yes, but need icon to change when I click pause script from taskbar.

Comment: You replace the tray menu with your own menu and own pause command, that way you jump to a "Pause:" label or handle it in the menuhandler: label in your script where you change the icon and then Pause. The menu acts as a toggle to turn it on/off and you can keep track of the state of it with a variable. See edit above.

Comment: That is the thing there is no pause command. I just want to right-click on taskbar icon and when I click pause in context menu(on the icon, on the taskbar), icon should change.

Comment: I don't think you can (easily) modify that menu, but it was possible (it seems) under windows 7 with additional code 1. forum post + example here https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/76485-jumplist-library-for-windows-7/  and 2. library you need (I think) https://github.com/rshipp/ahk-libs/blob/master/JumpList/JumpList.ahk - might be easier to use the tray menu or just setup a hotkey to do it